# Explicit layout margins defined in storyboard are discarded at runtime

Tags: xcode, uiview, autolayout, storyboard

In my storyboard, I set the layout margins on my view to **Explicit**, with a 30 value for the left.

[image]

Everything looks fine in the storyboard editor view:

[image]

... but when I launch my app, the layout margins go back to the default (8,8,8,8):

[image]

Attempting to read the value programmatically (`myView.layoutMargins`) shows that default value again. It's as though no matter what value I set in the layout margins, it does absolutely nothing at run time.

To reproduce:

1. Create a new view controller in IB.
2. Add a view and set the layout margins to explicit (30,8,8,8)
3. Create a top, left, width, and height constraints for the view.
4. Give the view a background color so it's easy to tell if the label is indented correctly or not.
5. Add a label as a subview of that view and pin it to the top and left margins.
6. Notice how in the storyboard, the label is indented by 30 pixels from the left.
7. Run the app. Notice how the label loses its 30 pixel indentation and instead restores back to the default 8 pixel.

Note: I'm using Xcode 7.

Comment: If you can reproduce it in such a simple isolated manner, it seems like a good candidate for [a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like it's fixed in Xcode 8.

However, if you try reading the `layoutMargins` value in `viewDidLoad` it won't report the value set in the storyboard. You have to wait until a later method is called such as `viewDidAppear` to see the correct value.

Comment: Hmm. I'm using 8.2.1, and I still see the problem when using explicit margins in table view cells' `contentView`s. :(